# Best way to set up conan in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, conan

#### Situation

- single C++ repo containing 20 projects
- Builds in MSVS for windows, uses cmake for Linux. Same code base builds for both platforms.

  - There's an msvs solution file connecting all projects in the repo together
- Trying to find best tools and workflow

#### What I have so far for Windows

- installed conan extension for msvs
- I have a conanfile.txt for a couple of projects (not all projects need them) and they're located in the root folder of each project (not the root folder of the repo).
- There's a "conan install for all projects in solution" button but that does nothing somehow.
- **Question1**: Is there an easier way for someone to install conan deps without having to right click on each project and select "Conan install for this project"?
- Conan extension's default install location is `$(OutputDir)\.conan`. So when I "conan install" a project through the tool, there are important `conan*.props` that the project would import. These `props` are now in the output folder (e.g. `x64/Debug`) that's ignored by git. If I pushed the repo in this state, the next guy who clones it won't be able to open the solution because the projects now reference the `props` but they're not present.

  - **Question2** I've changed the install location to `$(SolutionDir)\.conan`. Is this the common way to do it?
  - **Question3** Is there a way to default the conan msvs extension (maybe through settings files) so a new machine wouldn't go back to installing to `$(OutputDir)\.conan` and screwing up the repo?

I could be doing this all wrong so any best practices tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Conan" and "Best" are [trigger words](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo9buo9Mtos) for someone my age and background

Comment: @user4581301 got another package manager to recommend? It was between this and vcpkg. Conan seemed to be more efficient with storage and build time so here I am.

Comment: @user4581301 just saw the clip haha. I need to go back and watch that movie.

Comment: Some suggestions: the VS extension is not maintained at the moment, I suggest dropping it, and using the command line. Things will probably be simpler, more efficient, with a simple script in your project that setups the project. You need to define the project, do you want to define and create packages for those subprojects or only use third party dependencies (maybe from ConanCenter?). Also if all your dependencies should be the same for the 20 subprojects, you might be good with just 1 conanfile, and using MSBuildDeps and CMakeDeps, you can add the generated files per project.

Comment: I'd also recommend to submit this as a question to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, as it is easier to do extended discussions there than here.

Comment: @drodri I'll check out scripts and MSBuildDeps + CMakeDeps to see if those work. I have a few sets of subprojects that have the same dependencies. Gonna post the question to conan's github too. Thanks!

Comment: I am creating a blog post on how to setup a C++ environment using Conan, CMake and Visual Studio Code. You can look at https://www.ehu.ygp.mybluehost.me. any feedback is appreciated.

(didn't pay for a better domain name)